# How to disable all but one button in a JPanel and enable them one after the other

Tags: java, arrays, swing, if-statement, point

I created a JPanel with 11 buttons (all in an array). Now I set actionListeners on those buttons, but I want only one button to be enabled initially, then after the actionListener on it is completed, the next button is enabled. Here is my code!

```
public class Beginner extends JPanel {

    static JButton quest;
    Random rand = new Random();

    int n = 10;

    static List <Point> points = new ArrayList<Point> ();

    Quest1 q1;
    Quest2 q2;
    Quest3 q3;
    Quest4 q4;
    Quest5 q5;
    Quest6 q6;
    Quest7 q7;
    Quest8 q8;
    Quest9 q9;
    Quest10 q10;
    Quest11 q11;

    public Beginner() {

        int radius = 200;
        Point center = new Point (250, 250);

        double angle = Math.toRadians(360 / n);      
        points.add(center);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            double theta = i * angle;

            int dx = (int) (radius * Math.sin(theta));    
            int dy = (int) (radius * Math.cos(theta));
            Point p = new Point (center.x + dx , center.y + dy);
            points.add(p);
        }
        draw (points);
    }

    public void draw (List<Point> points) {
        JPanel panels = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout spring = new SpringLayout();
        int count = 1;
        for (Point point: points) {
            quest = new JButton("Question " + count);
            quest.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            Font fonte = new Font("Script MT Bold", Font.PLAIN, 20);
            quest.setFont(fonte);
            add (quest);
            count++;
            spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, quest, point.x, SpringLayout.WEST, panels );

            spring.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, quest, point.y, SpringLayout.NORTH, panels );
            setLayout(spring);
            panels.setOpaque(false);
            panels.setVisible(true);
            panels.setLocation(5,5);
            add(panels);
            //I want to disable all but one button at this point

            quest.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent p) {
                    if (point.equals(points.get(0))) {
                        q1 = new Quest1();
                        //then, enable the next after this is completed
                    }   
                    else if (point.equals(points.get(1))) {
                        q2 = new Quest2();
                        //same comment in Quest1 follows....and so on!
                    }
                    else if (point.equals(points.get(2))) {
                        q3 = new Quest3();
                    }
                    else if (point.equals(points.get(3))) {
                        q4 =  new Quest4();
                    }
                    else if (point.equals(points.get(4))) {
                        q5 = new Quest5();
                    }
                    else if (point.equals(points.get(5))) {
                        q6 = new Quest6();
                    }  
                    else if (point.equals(points.get(6))) {
                        q7 = new Quest7();
                    }  
                    else if (point.equals(points.get(7))) {
                        q8 = new Quest8();
                    }  
                    else if (point.equals(points.get(8))) {
                        q9 = new Quest9 () ;
                    }
                    else if (point.equals(points.get(9))) {
                        q10 = new Quest10() ;
                    }
                    else if (point.equals(points.get(10))) {
                        q11 =  new Quest11 ();
                    }
                } 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've code above that has nothing to do with your problem, and I suggest that you try to help us help you. I suggest that you start over and simplify -- create and post a [mcve] where you create a very simple program that contains a GUI that holds couple of buttons and where you try to solve your main problem, and then tell us what problems you're having with this code. Please be as specific and descriptive as possible.

Comment: You should consider re-doing the above code anyway since it contains much unneeded redundancy where you have many lines of code that all appear to be doing the exact same thing, as well as a bunch of Quest objects that appear to be happier were they held together in an ArrayList or array.

Comment: Also, ActionListeners should run almost instantaneously, and so your request (without further detail) doesn't really make sense, unless you want the buttons enabled *sequentially*. Please clarify.

Comment: Maybe you got it.....I want them enabled sequentially, like enabling one first, then enabling the second afterwards, that is what I'm talking about! I just wanted you people to get the whole picture!

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sequentially enablebuttons I would use at least two fields, an `ArrayList<JButton>` filled with your buttons, and an `int buttonListIndex` int index field to tell the program which button is active. You can enable and disable buttons via `setEnabled(true)`. In the ActionListener, increment the index int and use a for loop to loop through all the buttons, disabling all except the one that corresponds to the index. I'll leave the code implementation for this up to you.

Comment: If this was in a syntax...I would have loved it better! My buttons are already part of an arraylist.

Comment: @Presh_K7: don't cheat yourself out of the opportunity to code. Please try to do this yourself first. Again in your original question, I don't even see any attempt yet. If you get stuck in your attempt, post that in your question as an edit, and I'll work with you on it.

Comment: Ok! how do I create the int buttonListIndex to tell the program which button is active.... I'm confused!

Comment: How do you create any int variable? You then increment it when needed.

Comment: Please see my question on this link!....I need your help @http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39806053/output-mathematical-solvings-in-presentable-form